# Entity Framework optional:optional relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to set up an Entity Framework model with an optional:optional relationship:

In my situation, sometimes an AdditionalData record exists that points to a BaseTable record, but sometimes BaseTable or AdditionalData records exist without any linkage.  The foreign key to the BaseTable (if it exists) is on the AdditionalData table.

I want to be able to navigate back and forth between BaseTable and any AdditionalDatas that might be connected.

```
BaseTable  0..1 ----- 0..1 AdditionalData1
                 \
                  --- 0..1 AdditionalData2
```

```
public class BaseTable {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AdditionalType1 AdditionalType1 { get; set; }
    public virtual AdditionalType2 AdditionalType2 { get; set; }
}                  

public class AdditionalType1 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? BaseTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseTable BaseTable { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalType2 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? BaseTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseTable BaseTable { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make this work?  I got as far as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalType1>()
    .HasOptional(zmt => zmt.BaseTable)
    .WithOptionalDependent(zm => zm.AdditionalType1)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("BaseTableId"));
modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalType2>()
    .HasOptional(zmt => zmt.BaseTable)
    .WithOptionalDependent(zm => zm.AdditionalType2)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("BaseTableId"));
```

but it tells me this:

> error: (1564,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be
>   unique. Property name 'BaseTableId' was already defined.

I don't know exactly what that refers to, and not sure how to fix.

EDIT: If I remove the Map/MapKey clauses as suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016308/237091) I get this error instead, when a query runs that uses it:

> Invalid column name 'BaseTable_Id'
>   as it maps itself to BaseTable_Id automatically instead of my BaseTableId field.

Comment: 'Sometimes a BaseTable exists' Either you want to make rows in the base table for users or you have a very bad understanding of how databases work. It's not like Schrodinger's cat, whether your database has a Table has to be determined at design time.

Comment: @Mr Fox: Edited for clarification -- I was talking about records, not the actual existence of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to set up a 1:0..1 relationship from your `AdditionalType` objects (which I may have misinterpreted completely.

N.B. I think you would have to hold a BaseTableId on your `BaseTable` for this to work (or define a primary key):

If `BaseTableId` is the foreign key in this instance, I think this may be what you're after:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalType1>()
    .HasOptional(zmt => zmt.BaseTable)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.BaseTableId);
```

Which is what I've used previously, but can't admit to understanding it fully (the .WithMany() trips me up); it's a slight workaround listed in article from this answer: [Entity Framework 0..1 to 0 relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980260/entity-framework-0-1-to-0-relation))

Apologies if I've missed the point entirely.

Comment: yes use this approach.   this is 1:Many BUT you arent forced to put many entries in ;-)   1:1 declaration would require base table and Additional to have the same primary key.  And one to marked as Primary. So will need to add a custom check or add a unique index to guarantee 1:1

Comment: Sorry, just added Id prooperty.  I intended there to be a PK Id field on all of them, but not a Shared Primary Key for legacy reasons.

Comment: I'm a little sad that I have to pretend it's one-to-many to trick EF into working, but it does work.  Thanks!

Comment: It does feel a little strange, but I think (and seems to be mentioned) that it might be something addressed in later versions of EF. Ta!